# What volumes of the Campione LN correspond to the anime?

Tags: campione

I am just curious about which volumes the anime occurs in...

My guess is up to vol 5. or something

I want to start reading the LN series already but my problem is I don't know where to start... Yes, I know that I should start from the first volume up to the last but I get bored when I do that. I am not really sure about my guess, so please, help me...

Answer (score 1):

I know you're not here given that you've been away for 8 months but still:

The anime is such a mess...

Episode 1: volume 3

Episode 12: Original

The rest: It goes from volume 1 to volume 6 chapter 5

Notes: The Athena and Voban arcs are almost faithful to to the light novel. Perseus is semi-faithful. Ena has lots and lots of original content.

I read the light novels and saw the anime